# GetType Of Entity in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ query that want to select type of my entity like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var currentContext = new MyContext())
        {
            var x = (from c in currentContext.GeneralAccounts
                    select new  { CType = c.GetType() }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

But this query makes an error:

**ERROR**:  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a query like this

```
from c in currentContext.GeneralAccounts
select new  { CType = c.GetType() }
```

then the Entity Framework, or LINQ-to-SQL will try to form a SQL statement from it. For some things however there is no equivalent SQL statement, in your case it's the call to `GetType()` that's the problem.

What you want to do is to execute the `GetType()` on the client, not on the database server, so you'll have to change the query to

```
// this can be translated into a SQL query
(from c in currentContext.GeneralAccounts
 select c)
// turns the IQueryable into an IEnumerable, which means
// from now on LINQ-to-Objects is used
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(p => new { CType = p.GetType() })
.ToList()
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try this one:

```
var result  = (from c in currentContext.GeneralAccounts
               select c).AsEnumerable().Select(x=> new  { CType = x.GetType() }).ToList();
```

You were getting the error because the Linq expression get translated into SQL, and as `x.GetType()` can't be translated into SQL therefore you need to retrieve the records first by invoking AsEnumerable and then get its type.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq I have forgotten the put `()` after the `AsEnumerable`. I suppose that's the reason. However is a classic behavior from some person is SO, they downvote, without a reasoning. Certainly that helps a lot.

Comment: but it shouldn't be a big deal. :)

Comment: @AsifMushtaq I know...but what can we do? We have to leave with them.